# Real world application of finding all simple paths on a graph

Tags: graph-theory, applications, planar-graphs

I am currently designing a general purpose [graph database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database). Recently I have started to consider supporting the "**find all simple paths between two nodes**" operation on the graph. However while there are multitude of solutions to this problem I cannot find a single practical application for it. Everything I found started with the "I want to find all paths between two nodes on a graph". But why? For what purpose? What problem can this operation help to solve? Is it useful in path finding, networking or some other area? I would like to see some practical use cases to model the tests of the algorithm after.